# ADB could not be found, while trying to run appium on windows 10 64bit

Tags: appium

Adb could not be found, while trying to run appium server, how can I solve it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqUud.png

Answer (score 0):

Check if ADB is present in the below location -

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

If it's available, then you have to add the above location to the PATH variable in Environment properties. This should resolve the issue.

Also, to double check after you add the location to the path, just open command prompt and run the command - `adb version`

If the location is set properly, you will see the adb version on running the command -

```
C:\Users\anish>adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 84e3321d5db3-android
```

Comment: I did it before posting the question,adb.exe file exist in the folder, already set the path, and run the command adb version in cmd, and got the bellow version name: `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 8f855a3d9b35-android` but issue still exist! :(

Answer (score 0):

I Suspect adb.exe file doesn't exist in the platform-tools folder. Check it once again.

Comment: I did it before posting the question,adb.exe file exist in the folder, already set the path, and run the command adb version in cmd, and got the bellow version name: `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 8f855a3d9b35-android` but issue still exist! :(